# Question on the angle between two vectors

Tags: calculus

Copy the axes and vector shown here. Then shade in the points $(x,y)$ for which $(x \textbf{i} +y \textbf{j}) \cdot \textbf{v} \leq 0$

[image]

I'm looking at the solution which says:

$(x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j})\cdot \textbf{v}=|x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}||\textbf{v}|\cos{\theta}\leq0$

when $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \pi$. This means $(x,y)$ has to be a point whose position vector makes an angle with $\textbf{v}$ that is a right angle or bigger.

[image]

I understand that $\cos\theta=\frac{\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{v}}{|\textbf{u}||\textbf{v}|}$ which is where they get

$(x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j})\cdot \textbf{v}=|x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}||\textbf{v}|\cos{\theta}\leq0$

My issue is understanding why $\theta$ needs to be between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$. I thought cosine was negative from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$ so why is their restriction of $\theta$ different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between two vectors is fully and uniquely specified in the interval $[0,π].$

After all, saying that said angle is $200^\circ$ is equivalent to saying that it's $160^\circ.$

Consequently, the angle between to vectors is conventionally defined to be between $0$ and $π,$ both inclusive.

(On the other hand, the angle between two lines is defined to be between $0$ and $\fracπ2,$ both inclusive.)

Comment: awesome, thank you. I thought that this might be the answer but I wasn't sure.